# How to share a folder on windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, domain-controller, server-message-block

I have a Windows Server 2008 on my virtual machine. I created a domain controller and want to share one folder with one user.

If I try to connect to the folder, I should enter the Username, Password and the domain name. The connection works, but the entered domain name doesn't matter. I can enter anything and it will connect to the folder.

How to avert this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the current shared folder permissions. Probably you have access to Everyone. If you want allow access just to your domain users, Add Domain Users group on Security / Shared Permissions tab.